# Javascript show/hide items based on value

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a website for a client that sells stuff.
I haven't made anything yet, this is the concept stage.

The idea is that *x* products are shown.
Each product has it's own value.

So let's say we have 4 products

1. Product 1 = $10
2. Product 2 = $25
3. Product 3 = $50
4. Product 4 = $100

The user doesn't see the values and the amount he is allowed to spent.

Let's say the user has a total ammount of $150 to spent.
If he clicks product 4 he has a total amount of $50 left.
The trick is now to only show the proucts that are $50 or less.

Does anybody know what the smartest way of approaching this is?
I think Javascript but love to hear your opinion.
I can't be the first to do this so are there any examples/tutorials/freebies/etc ...?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Nope nothing but I'm currently in concept phase so first let's start with an idea!

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with int variables.Maybe the best way is to make an ajax call to the server and update the list of products looking at the server response.

Send the current amount to server and return the list of products than have a price with equal or less value